# Replace string using grep and sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed, grep

I have bunch of files in a directory,
I need to change prefix of lines in file like "AB_" to "YZ_"
how can i do it?

i have used  grep and sed like,

`grep -nr "AB_" ./ | xargs -0 sed -i 's/AB_/YZ_/g'`

but giving error,
`: File name too long`

example string in a file are: `Hello AB_WORLD!` and `Hello WORLD_AB!`

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs: Using -0 for xargs deals with the problem, but many Unix utilities cannot use NUL as separator (e.g. head, tail, ls, echo, sed, tar -v, wc, which).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed will take multiple files as arguments, so this should work:

```
sed -i '/AB_/s//YZ_/g' *
```

(Note that `-i` is non-standard)

Answer (score 0):

You mean  `grep -lr` not `grep -nr`

`-l` gives you the file name; `-n` gives you the matching line with line number prepended

Comment: with this change its giving,
 
sed: can't read ** file name **
: No such file or directory

Comment: Do these filenames have weird characters (for various senses of "weird"; whitespace could screw this up,  for instance)? (sed doesn't have the equivalent of `-0` or `--null`)

Answer (score 0):

I like Perl for this one:
The -i option will save the original file with a.bak extension.

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/^AB_/YZ_/' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -lr "AB_" ./ | while read file
do
  echo "Change file $file ..."
  sed -i 's/AB_/YZ_/g' ${file}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

sed one-liner answer

Find php files in the directory containing string "foo" and replace all occurences with "bar"

grep -l foo *.php | xargs sed -i '' s/foo/bar/g

To recurse through directories

grep -rl foo * | xargs sed -i '' s/foo/bar/g

(just done successfully on 8100 files)

grep -rl bar * | wc -l
    8102